# MongoDB Query: `currentOp` very high read lock but low number in `explain`

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I'm investigating performance downgrade issue of my application through MongoDB command `db.currentOp`. I found there are some queries in the result with very high value of `timeLockedMicros.r: 7009711`, `timeAcquiringMicros.r: 3507005` and `secs_running: 4`.

But when I tried to execute that query it ran fast. And when I `explain` this query the result looked good as below.

```
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor to.id_1",
"n" : 3857,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"nYields" : 0,
"nscanned" : 3857,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 4362,
"nscannedObjects" : 3857,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 4362,
"millisShardTotal" : 43,
"millisShardAvg" : 43,
"numQueries" : 1,
"numShards" : 1,
"indexBounds" : {
    "to.id" : [
        [
            "56a1aacf252b41c76aac61c9",
            "56a1aacf252b41c76aac61c9"
        ]
    ]
},
"millis" : 44
```

I don't understand why it uses ~7000 seconds of read lock and ran 4 seconds while used 44 milliseconds when I executed.